# Verify Gauss' Theorem for the vector field over region which is a cylinder.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

(5) Verify Gauss' Theorem for the vector field $F = (x^2, -y, z)$ over the
region $V$, where $V$ is the solid cylinder $y^2 + z^2 \le 9$, $0 \le x \le 2$.

So here is what I tried :
I tried to parameterize $r(t) = < t, 3 \sin t,3 \cos t>$ . Now I want to find the normal to the side but I cannot seem to understand how to do it.

Comment: A surface must be parametrized using **2** variables, not one. What you have is a line (a helix)

Comment: Don’t forget the disks at the ends, too!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, your parametrization of the cylinder is wrong. You have correctly chosen $x=t$ or correctly chosen $y=3\sin t$ and $z=3\cos t$. But the $t$ for $x$ is not the same as $t$ for the $yz$ parametrization. Let's suppose you choose some $y$ and $z$ values such as $y^2+z^2=3$, or equivalent you chose a $t$ value. The $x$ value can be anything between $0$ and $2$, independent of $t$. So let's call this $s$. Then
$$\vec r(s,t)=\langle s,3\sin t, 3\cos t\rangle$$
Now a vector tangent to the surface can be obtained by taking teh derivative of $\vec r$ with respect to either $s$ or $t$:
$$\frac{\partial\vec r(s,t)}{\partial s}=\langle1,0,0\rangle\\\frac{\partial\vec r(s,t)}{\partial t}=\langle 0,3\cos t,-3\sin t\rangle$$
Then the normal is just the cross product
$$\vec n=\langle1,0,0\rangle\times\langle 0,3\cos t,-3\sin t\rangle=\langle 0,3\sin t,3\cos t\rangle$$